# Julia : eigs() function returning different values after every evaluation

Tags: julia, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I noticed that after running [eigs()](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/linalg/#Base.eigs) function multiple times, every time it gives different but approximate result.

Is there way to return it every time the same result ? Output is sometimes with "+" sign or "-" sign.

Content of **M** :

```
[2, 1]  =  1.0
[3, 1]  =  0.5
[1, 2]  =  1.0
[3, 2]  =  2.5
[1, 3]  =  0.5
[2, 3]  =  2.5

M = M+M'
(d, v) = eigs(M, nev=1, which=:LR)
```

I tried running same function on same sparse matrix in Python , although the matrix looks bit different I think it is same. Just left values are numbered from 0. In julia they are numbered from 1. I do not know if that is a big difference. Values are approximately same in Julia and Python but in Python they are always the same after every evaluation. Also return values in python are **complex numbers**, in Julia **real**.

**Python code:**

Content of **M.T** :

```
from scipy.sparse import linalg

(1, 0)  1.0
(2, 0)  0.5
(0, 1)  1.0
(2, 1)  2.5
(0, 2)  0.5
(1, 2)  2.5

eigenvalue, eigenvector = linalg.eigs(M.T, k=1, which='LR')
```

Any idea why this behavior is occurring ?

**Edit :**

These are results of four evaluations of eigs

```
==========eigvalues==============
[2.8921298144977587]
===========eigvector=============
[-0.34667468634025667
-0.679134250677923
-0.6469878912367839]
=================================

==========eigvalues==============
[2.8921298144977596]
===========eigvector=============
[0.34667468634025655
0.6791342506779232
0.646987891236784]
=================================

==========eigvalues==============
[2.8921298144977596]
===========eigvector=============
[0.34667468634025655
0.6791342506779233
0.6469878912367841]
=================================

==========eigvalues==============
[2.8921298144977583]
===========eigvector=============
[0.3466746863402567
0.679134250677923
0.646987891236784]
=================================
```

Comment: I tried raising number of iterations. I am not so concerned that number are slightly different. I am concerned about that "-" sign. In Python no matter how many times I run it, there are never "-" signs in result for this input data.

Comment: Correction: after the edit it seems that not the number of iterations is the problem. The algorithm is probably oscillating towards the solution and sometimes it finds it from top and sometimes from bottom and it stops if maximum precision (difference smaller eps = unmeasurable) is reached.

Comment: And is there some way how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't know, the values are probably "close enough", although that depends on the application. Python's algorithm is not necessarily better, just deterministic it seems.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `eigs` is supposed to be deterministic. Eventually, the goal is for `eigs` to be in pure Julia, but I think it still depends on ARPACK which has caused problems in the past. Relevant google groups reading and issues page [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/ZTSfIDLpYpE) and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6965). As suggested at those pages, older versions of ARPACK are a bit buggy and all the fixes may not have propagated through yet depending on your distro. This *might* be the source of your problem...

Comment: The eigenvectors of a matrix are defined up to a scalar. That is, if *v* is an eigenvector, so is *2v* and *-v*. The big variations in the output above are due to this freedom of choice for the algorithm. If the eigenvectors are normalized (multiplied to have norm `1` and say a positive first component) then the vectors should be the same. Caveat: there is some more freedom when eigenvalues are the same (have high multiplicity).

Comment: If you file an issue on the Julia issue tracker, this will get fixed: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues. As @maraca said, this isn't wrong, it's just annoying that it's non-deterministic.

Comment: So can I use random  solution from these evaluations as correct result for my function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `eigs` depends on the initial vector for the Lanczos iterations. When not specified, it is random so even though all the vectors returned are correct the phase is not guaranteed to be the same over different iterations.

If you want the result to be the same every time, you can set `v0` in eigs, e.g.

`eigs(M, nev=1, which=:LR, v0 = ones(3))`

As long as `v0` doesn't change you should get deterministic results.

Note that if you want a deterministic result for testing purposes, you might want to consider a testing scheme that allows phase shifts since the phase can shift with the smallest perturbations. E.g. if you link a different BLAS or change the number of threads the result might change again.

Comment: Yes, but which **v0** vector to choose. Python uses it too and it is random by every iteration. Also I think it is not random in Julia when not specified, because according to specification it is equal to this **v0=zeros((0, ))** when argument is not specified.

Comment: I am using **Julia v0.3**. Do you think that upgrading to **v0.4** can fix my problem ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you choose as long as you choose the same one every time. There might be slight differences between how fast `eigs` will converge for different starting values but you can't really tell which one is faster a priori.

You can set the seed with `srand` and then use `rand` to initialize the vector and you should be fine.

Regarding the `zeros((0,))` part then you'll have to dig a little deeper in the source. Then you can see that when the vector is empty the starting residual is set to uninitialized memory. It's not optimal and probably not intentional but it's random.

Comment: Yes but I am implementing it in my own function so by using **rand** there will be different **v0** for every execution of this function and that could be problem when someone will try it more times on same input of matrix, doesn't it ?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your function I think you should provide a `v0` as an argument so users can set this. If you think that it too much detail to expose to the user then try `ones(n)` and see how it works. It might work okay for your problem or it might not.

Comment: I am implementing algorithm for computing eigenvector centrality of nodes in graph. It will be wrapped in function and input is graph, so desirability is that result is deterministic for one graph even when user runs function for centrality multiple times. I can hard-code **v0** to be same for every runtime of function, or does not need to be same, a little deviation does not matter to me. What matters is that one time it is **plus** and one **minus**.

Comment: The eigenvectors produced by `eigs` are only determined up to a sign flip. That is just how eigenvectors work mathematically. The plus version is as correct as the minus version. Another solution might be to post process the vectors such that the e.g. the first element is always positive, i.e. multiply the vectors with the signs of the first elements. Then you allow a random initialization vector and get almost deterministic results (they might deviate with floatingpoint errors.)

Comment: I found that there is issue with LAPACK and fix is to link LAPACK 2.0 any idea how to do it ?